# Alternative to “detestability”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, american-english

I have the following sentence,

> This we have heard and seen, as others beside us have seen; how can it
>   not be, when nowadays some famous books of the madhāhib rule such
>   cases of invalidity or **detestability**.

I need an alternative for “detestability” as I can't find its definition in any standard online dictionary. I've found an entry in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/detestability) but I'd prefer a word defined by a standard dictionary.

Comment: It's just a simple addition of _-ability_ to _detest_. I for one get the meaning.

Comment: The noun form of *detestable* is *detestableness*, but did you want a word that rhymes with *invalidity*?

Comment: The sentence doesn't quite make sense to me. Do you mean to say the madhāhib rule over such cases? or that the madhāhib rule such cases as invalid or detestable?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox, It's part of a longer discussion. The latter is what is intended, i.e. “the madhāhib rule such cases as invalid or detestable.” This can be inferred from the context.

Comment: @jxh Yes “detestable” is what I was looking for. If you have something that rhymes with “invalidity,” that would be better. The document is expected to be read by non-native speakers though so I prefer to use words that can be looked up.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand. If it is 'rule' in the sense of 'judge', then it would be written "rule such cases as invalid or detestable".

Comment: There's **despicablility**

Comment: @SteveLovell, “despicability” fits perfectly. I am also going to consider KitZ.Fox's suggestion but your answer is what I wanted. Please add it as an answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per other comments, I'm not entirely sure what your sentence structure really permits, but if you need a word like *detestability* then you may be happy with *despicability*.

> **despicable** *adjective*
>
> - deserving to be despised : so worthless or obnoxious as to rouse moral indignation
> - "despicable behavior"
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despicable)

The noun form *despicability* is not especially common, but is certainly known:

> **despicability**
>
> - a despicable quality or aspect
> - … when writers present to the world someone as unsympathetic as John Self or Humbert Humbert, they tend to sweeten the pill by offsetting the character's despicability with likeable qualities: irony, japery, or a fancy prose style. — David Annand, The (London) Sunday Telegraph, 4 May 2014
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despicability)

Based on [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=%28despicability*500%29%2Cdespicable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28despicability%20%2A%20500%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdespicable%3B%2Cc0), it looks like *despicable* is around 500 times more common than *despicability*